# What's the best wallet for Cardano?

Tags: wallet

I'm new to crypto all together. I was just wandering what you all think the best cardano wallet is?

I found a interesting post talking about it [here.](https://bullishreport.com/wallets/best-cardano-wallet)

I heard that ledger was the best choice. I'm currently debating. Can you please share some others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" wallet and the choice to pick a wallet depends on multiple factors which the user may find of interest- list includes but is not limited to:

- It's UI (how it looks /your interaction with it)
- NFT visual support
- Compliance with any Cardano Standards for voting purposes
- light (Yoroi) vs heavy (deadlaus) for memory consumption
- Current support for dapps which utilize said wallet for transactions
- many other factors ...etc....

I would recommend trying out different wallets and seeing which one suits you best for your personal needs.